# What platforms of the Death Rally remake does [death-rally-2012] cover? It should probably be renamed or made a synonym if it's for all platforms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, ambiguous-tags

Does [death-rally-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-rally-2012) refer to the Death Rally remake for the PC released in 2012 only, or is it also for the Android and iOS versions?

From watching [Youtube videos of the Death Rally remake on the iPhone](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=death%20rally%20iphone&search=Search), it seems that the iOS and PC versions are the same game. (Can anyone verify? I've only played the PC version.)

[Wikipedia also states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Rally):

> The 2011 remake of [the] game was also released for the PC platform on August 3rd, 2012.

...which implies that they are the same game. If so, the iOS (and probably also the Android version) and the PC version should all be covered by one tag only.

And if they are the same game, then this tag should be renamed (or made a tag synonym of) [death-rally-2011](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-rally-2011) or another better tag name instead to avoid confusion, as [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Rally), it was first released in 2011 for iOS.

**How do we define this tag's scope and usage, and what should be done about its name?**

Answer (score 2):

2011 probably is more accurate. However, [according to Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=death%20rally%202011,%20death%20rally%202012), Death Rally 2012 is a much more popular search:
[image: 2011: 0, 2012: 35]

Also, that's what [Metacritic](http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/death-rally-2012) and [Gamespot](http://www.gamespot.com/death-rally-2012/) call it, at least for the PC.

So I would say to keep the current tag, even if it's not too accurate for the mobile releases.
Regardless, [death-rally-2011](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-rally-2011) would make a good synonym.

Answer (score 0):

I think the game tag should refer to the game in general.  If people need to specify a platform, they can add an additional PC, iOS, or Android tag to do so.

As for whether it's 2011 or 2012, whatever it's better known as is what it should be tagged with, not necessarily what is more technically accurate.

Comment: "*Whatever it's better known as*" is subjective though, while "*what is more technically accurate*" is objective.